# Different location for mercurial repository and project folder?

Tags: svn, mercurial

I'm very new to Mercurial, I have worked with SVN before, but now I installed Mercurial as a local version control system. Now what I want to achieve is to have my IDE project folder in for example `C:\Projects\` and my Mercurial repo in `C:\Repo\`. The thing is I only want to keep `.cpp` and `.h` files in my Repo and the rest including the source files in my projects folder. Is it possible to have something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: First, why would you want that? Second, what's wrong with using .hgignore to simply ignore files that shouldn't be version-controlled?

Comment: Well, I need to give my whole repo to someone on a regular basis. He just wants the .cpp and .h files in the repo, but needs to look at my changes. Unfortunately I have no other option than this. I have to use local Mercurial and there must not be other files in the repo.

Comment: Um...so what's wrong with using the [hg archive](https://selenic.com/hg/help/archive) command, similar to [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)? If you *were* using SVN as your version control, you would have the same problem trying to send .cpp and .h files without the temporary files and .svn folder.

Comment: I have looked into that, but it seems that this produces an unversioned archive. I need all the commits and changes. The .svn/hg folders are fine, but I don't need any .project files from my IDE

Comment: @Ben: `hg serve` will be more HG-way, BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** That's what the .hgignore file and `hg pull` are for. In fact, easy distribution of version-controlled files (and only those files) to others is kind of the whole point of Mercurial.

You can't have your repository somewhere other than where your working folder is, without doing some very dicey copying or linking (which is hard to do, anyway, on a Windows system).

Instead, use an .hgignore file to exclude some files from the repository and `hg pull` to make the updates available.

Steps:

1. Use .hgignore with a regex syntax to ignore everything other than `.cpp` and `.h` files, like this:

```
# regexp syntax.
syntax: regexp
\.(?!cpp|h)[^.]+$
```

That regex ignores anything that has a `.whatever` ending that is not `.cpp` or `.h`.

2. Then, whenever your colleague needs the repo, he can do an `hg pull` to get exactly what's in the repo and nothing else.

Even if you can't do a *remote* `hg pull` for some reason, you can do a *local* pull or clone (i.e., to your own hard drive), then zip up the new directory and send it to him. It will only include the version-controlled files, not anything else you may have in your working directory (like `.project` files). Note, however, that hg is really intended to be used in a networked context.

Comment: Nice attempt, but but bad *idea* for Mercurial's noob... and dirty regexp, too error-prone. `hg st
? .hgignore
? b.cpp
? c.h
? d.hpp
? dir\b.cpp
? dir\c.h
? dir\d.hpp
? dir\e.h1
? e.h1`

Comment: Great that's exactly what I wanted, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. You **can not** have repository in any other place, than `.hg` folder inside your working dir
2. You **can** add to version control only part (i.e. only needed) of existing files in your tree

Comment: In order to expand on that: Ignore *all* files so that they don't bother you at `hg status`. And only add those you're interested in (the *.cpp and *.h) files to the repo.